# My last column does not show, I use chart.js 2.5

Tags: chart.js

My last column does not show, I use chart.js 2.5,the framework is used laravel 5.4，the data has been confirmed into the incoming.

Look at this figure:

[image: Look at this figure]

data has been into the incoming :

[image: data has been into the incoming]

```
var ctxBar = $('#barChart');
var data2 = {
    labels: {!!json_encode($project_names, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) !! },
    datasets: [{
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: {!!json_encode(TasksCountArray($projects), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) !! }
    }]
};

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctxBar, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data2,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Projects Tasks'
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        fullWidth: true
    }
});
```

Comment: This problem has been solved.

Comment: the Y-axis started not at 0 by default. It's possible to add an option for that。

Comment: options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }